# Google Visualization API. Graphs are not displaying in gsp pages

Tags: grails-2.0

I am developing application with grails.  Below is the list of Program I use.
- Groovy/Grails Tool Suite   Version: 3.5.1.RELEASE   Platform: Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2)
- Grails 2.3.8
- Java : jdk1.6.0_45

my problem is having installed google visualization plugin by specifying in the BuildConfig.groovy with the code below

```
plugins {        
    compile ":google-visualization:0.7"
}
```

and tried the sample below but the chart are not displaying.
there seems to be no error what so ever. What I suspect is that the application does not recognise the tag .
anybody has come across this problem, your help would be very much appreciated.

Cheers,

Sura

```
<%@ page import="org.grails.plugins.google.visualization.data.Cell; org.grails.plugins.google.visualization.util.DateUtil" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Visualization API plugin</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <gvisualization:apiImport/>
</head>
   <body>
   <%
      def calendarColumns = [['date', 'Date'], ['number', 'Won/Loss']]
      def calendarData = [[DateUtil.createDate(2012, 3, 13), 37032], [DateUtil.createDate(2012, 3, 14), 38024], [DateUtil.createDate(2012, 3, 15), 38024], [DateUtil.createDate(2012, 3, 16), 38108], [DateUtil.createDate(2012, 3, 17), 38229]]
      def timelineColumns = [['string', 'President'], ['date', 'Start'], ['date', 'End']]
      def timelineData = [['Washington',  DateUtil.createDate(1789, 3, 29),  DateUtil.createDate(1797, 2, 3)], ['Adams',  DateUtil.createDate(1797, 2, 3),  DateUtil.createDate(1801, 2, 3)], ['Jefferson',  DateUtil.createDate(1801, 2, 3),  DateUtil.createDate(1809, 2, 3)]]
      def myDailyActivitiesColumns = [['string', 'Task'], ['number', 'Hours per Day']]
      def myDailyActivitiesData = [['Work', 11], ['Eat', 2], ['Commute', 2], ['Watch TV', 2], ['Sleep', 7]]
      def companyPerformanceColumns = [['string', 'Year'], ['number', 'Sales'], ['number', 'Expenses']]
      def companyPerformanceData = [['2004', 1000, 400], ['2005', 1170, 460], ['2006', 660, 1120], ['2007', 1030, 540]]
      def yearlyExpensesColumns = [['string', 'Year'], ['number', 'Expenses'], ['number', 'Sales']]
      def yearlyExpensesData = [['2004', 1000, 900], ['2005', 1170, 1000], ['2006', 660, 660], ['2007', 1030, 1000]]
      def weightByAgeColumns = [['number', 'Age'], ['number', 'Weight']]
      def weightByAgeData = [[8, 12], [4, 5.5], [11, 14], [4, 5], [3, 3.5], [6.5, 7]]
      def countByDayColumns = [['string', 'Day'], ['number', ''], ['number', ''], ['number', ''], ['number', '']]
      def countByDayData = [['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45], ['Tues', 31, 38, 55, 66], ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80], ['Thurs', 50, 77, 66, 77], ['Fri', 15, 66, 22, 68]]
      def monthlyCoffeeProdByCountryColumns = [['string', 'Month'], ['number', 'Bolivia'], ['number', 'Ecuador'], ['number', 'Madagascar'], ['number', 'Papua  Guinea'], ['number', 'Rwanda'], ['number', 'Average']]
      def monthlyCoffeeProdByCountryData = [['2004/05', 165, 938, 522, 998, 450, 614.6], ['2005/06', 135, 1120, 599, 1268, 288, 682], ['2006/07', 157, 1167, 587, 807, 397, 623], ['2007/08', 139, 1110, 615, 968, 215, 609.4], ['2008/09', 136, 691, 629, 1026, 366, 569.6]]
      def revenueAndLicensesColumns = [['number', 'Revenue'], ['number', 'Licenses']]
      def revenueAndLicensesData = [[435, 132], [438, 131], [512, 137], [460, 142], [491, 140], [487, 139], [552, 147], [511, 146], [505, 151], [509, 149]]
      def gainersLoserColumns = [['string', 'Name'], ['number', ''], ['number', ''], ['number', ''], ['number', '']]
      def gainersLoserData = [['Gainers', 10, 30, 45, 60], ['Losers', 20, 35, 25, 45]]
      def systemPerformanceColumns = [['string', 'Label'], ['number', 'Value']]
      def systemPerformanceData = [['Memory', 80], ['CPU', 55], ['Network', 68]]
      def employeeColumns = [['string', 'Name'], ['string', 'Salary'], ['boolean', 'Full Time Employee']]
      def employeeData = [['Mike', '$10,000', true], ['Jim', '$8,000', false], ['Alice', '$12,500', true], ['Bob', '$7,000', true]]
      def mapColumns = [['number', 'Lat'], ['number', 'Lon'], ['string', 'Name']]
      def mapData = [[37.4232, -122.0853, 'Work'], [37.4289, -122.1697, 'University'], [37.6153, -122.3900, 'Airport'], [37.4422, -122.1731, 'Shopping']]
      def pensColumns = [['date', 'Date'], ['number', 'Sold Pencils'], ['string', 'title1'], ['string', 'text1'], ['number', 'Sold Pens'], ['string', 'title2'], ['string', 'text2']]
      def pensData = [[DateUtil.createDate(2008, 1, 1), 30000, null, null, 40645, null, null], [DateUtil.createDate(2008, 1, 2), 14045, null, null, 20374, null, null], [DateUtil.createDate(2008, 1, 3), 55022, null, null, 50766, null, null], [DateUtil.createDate(2008, 1, 4), 75284, null, null, 14334, 'Out of Stock','Ran out of stock on pens at 4pm'], [DateUtil.createDate(2008, 1, 5), 41476, 'Bought Pens','Bought 200k pens', 66467, null, null], [DateUtil.createDate(2008, 1, 6), 33322, null, null, 39463, null, null]]
      def orgColumns = [['string', 'Name'], ['string', 'Manager'], ['string', 'ToolTip']]
      def orgData = [[new Cell(value: 'Mike', label: 'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'), '', 'The President'], [new Cell(value: 'Jim', label: 'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President<div>'), 'Mike', 'VP'], ['Alice', 'Mike', ''], ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'], ['Carol', 'Bob', '']]
      def populationColumns = [['string', '', 'Country'], ['number', 'Population (mil)', 'a'], ['number', 'Area (km2)', 'b']]
      def populationData = [['CN', 1324, 9640821], ['IN', 1133, 3287263], ['US', 304, 9629091], ['ID', 232, 1904569], ['BR', 187, 8514877]]
      def popularityColumns = [['string', 'Country'], ['number', 'Popularity']]
      def popularityData = [['Germany', 200], ['United States', 300], ['Brazil', 400], ['Canada', 500], ['France', 600], ['RU', 700]]
      def fruitColumns = [['string', 'Fruit'], ['date', 'Date'], ['number', 'Sales'], ['number', 'Expenses'], ['string', 'Location']]
      def fruitData = [['Apples', DateUtil.createDate(1988, 0, 1), 1000, 300, 'East'], ['Oranges', DateUtil.createDate(1988, 0, 1), 1150, 200, 'West'], ['Bananas', DateUtil.createDate(1988, 0, 1), 300, 250, 'West'], ['Apples', DateUtil.createDate(1989, 6, 1), 1200, 400, 'East'], ['Oranges', DateUtil.createDate(1989, 6, 1), 750, 150, 'West'], ['Bananas', DateUtil.createDate(1989, 6, 1), 788, 617, 'West']]
      def marketByRegionColumns = [['string', 'Region'], ['string', 'Parent'], ['number', 'Market trade volume (size)'], ['number', 'Market increase/decrease (color)']]
      def marketByRegionData = [['Global', null, 0, 0], ['America', 'Global', 0, 0], ['Europe', 'Global', 0, 0], ['Asia', 'Global', 0, 0], ['Australia', 'Global', 0, 0], ['Africa', 'Global', 0, 0], ['Brazil', 'America', 11, 10], ['USA', 'America', 52, 31], ['Mexico', 'America', 24, 12], ['Canada', 'America', 16, -23], ['France', 'Europe', 42, -11], ['Germany', 'Europe', 31, -2], ['Sweden', 'Europe', 22, -13], ['Italy', 'Europe', 17, 4], ['UK', 'Europe', 21, -5], ['China', 'Asia', 36, 4], ['Japan', 'Asia', 20, -12], ['India', 'Asia', 40, 63], ['Laos', 'Asia', 4, 34], ['Mongolia', 'Asia', 1, -5], ['Israel', 'Asia', 12, 24], ['Iran', 'Asia', 18, 13], ['Pakistan', 'Asia', 11, -52], ['Egypt', 'Africa', 21, 0], ['S. Africa', 'Africa', 30, 43], ['Sudan', 'Africa', 12, 2], ['Congo', 'Africa', 10, 12], ['Zair', 'Africa', 8, 10]]
      def accumulatedRatingColumns = [['string', 'Director (Year)'], ['number', 'Rotten Tomatoes'], ['number', 'IMDB']]
      def accumulatedRatingData = [['Alfred Hitchcock (1935)', 8.4, 7.9], ['Ralph Thomas (1959)', 6.9, 6.5], ['Don Sharp (1978)',6.5, 6.4], ['James Hawes (2008)', 4.4, 6.2]]
      def lifeExpectancyFertilityRateColumns =[['string', 'ID'], ['number', 'Life Expectancy'], ['number', 'Fertility Rate'], ['string', 'Region'], ['number', 'Population']]
      def lifeExpectancyFertilityRateData = [['CAN', 80.66, 1.67, 'North America', 33739900], ['DEU', 79.84, 1.36, 'Europe', 81902307], ['DNK', 78.6, 1.84, 'Europe', 5523095], ['EGY', 72.73, 2.78, 'Middle East', 79716203], ['GBR', 80.05, 2, 'Europe', 61801570], ['IRN', 72.49, 1.7, 'Middle East', 73137148], ['IRQ', 68.09, 4.77, 'Middle East', 31090763], ['ISR', 81.55, 2.96, 'Middle East', 7485600], ['RUS', 68.6, 1.54, 'Europe', 141850000], ['USA', 78.09, 2.05, 'North America', 307007000]]
      def candlestickOptions = [hollowIsRising: true]

   %>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function selectHandler(e) {
          alert('A table row was selected');
      }

      function readyHandler(e) {
          console.log('Table is ready');
      }
   </script>
   <h2>Google Visualization API Examples</h2>
   <gvisualization:pieCoreChart elementId="piechart" title="My Daily Activities" width="${450}" height="${300}" columns="${myDailyActivitiesColumns}" data="${myDailyActivitiesData}" />
   <gvisualization:imagePieChart elementId="imagepiechart" width="${430}" height="${240}" title="My Daily Activities" columns="${myDailyActivitiesColumns}" data="${myDailyActivitiesData}" />
   <gvisualization:barCoreChart elementId="barchart" title="Company Performance" width="${400}" height="${240}" vAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Year', titleColor: 'red')}" columns="${companyPerformanceColumns}" data="${companyPerformanceData}" />
   <gvisualization:imageBarChart elementId="imagebarchart" width="${400}" height="${240}" min="${0}" columns="${companyPerformanceColumns}" data="${companyPerformanceData}" />
   <gvisualization:bubbleCoreChart elementId="bubblechart" title="Correlation between life expectancy, fertility rate and population of some world countries (2010)" hAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Life Expectancy')}" vAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Fertility Rate')}" bubble="${new Expando(textStyle: '{fontSize: 11}')}" columns="${lifeExpectancyFertilityRateColumns}" data="${lifeExpectancyFertilityRateData}" />
   <gvisualization:columnCoreChart elementId="columnchart" title="Company Performance" width="${400}" height="${240}" hAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Year', titleColor: 'red')}" columns="${companyPerformanceColumns}" data="${companyPerformanceData}" />
   <gvisualization:areaCoreChart elementId="areachart" title="Company Performance" width="${400}" height="${240}" hAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Year', titleColor: 'red')}" columns="${companyPerformanceColumns}" data="${companyPerformanceData}" />
   <gvisualization:imageAreaChart elementId="imageareachart" width="${400}" height="${240}" min="${300}" max="${1400}" title="Yearly Expenses and Sales" columns="${yearlyExpensesColumns}" data="${yearlyExpensesData}" />       
   <gvisualization:lineCoreChart elementId="linechart" width="${400}" height="${240}" title="Company Performance" columns="${companyPerformanceColumns}" data="${companyPerformanceData}" />
   <gvisualization:imageLineChart elementId="imagelinechart" width="${400}" height="${240}" min="${0}" columns="${companyPerformanceColumns}" data="${companyPerformanceData}" />
   <gvisualization:scatterCoreChart elementId="scatterchart" width="${400}" height="${240}" title="Age vs. Weight comparison" hAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15)}" vAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15)}" legend="none" columns="${weightByAgeColumns}" data="${weightByAgeData}" />
   <gvisualization:steppedAreaCoreChart elementId="steppedareachart" width="${400}" height="${240}" title="The decline of \'The 39 Steps\'" vAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Accumulated Rating')}" isStacked="${true}" columns="${accumulatedRatingColumns}" data="${accumulatedRatingData}" />
   <gvisualization:candlestickCoreChart elementId="candlestickchart" legend="none" columns="${countByDayColumns}" data="${countByDayData}" candlestick="${new Expando(candlestickOptions)}" />
   <gvisualization:comboCoreChart elementId="combochart" title="Monthly Coffee Production by Country" vAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Cups')}" hAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Month')}" seriesType="bars" series="${new Expando(5: new Expando(type: 'line'))}" columns="${monthlyCoffeeProdByCountryColumns}" data="${monthlyCoffeeProdByCountryData}" />
   <gvisualization:imageSparkLine elementId="imagesparkline" width="${120}" height="${40}" showAxisLines="${false}" showValueLabels="${false}" labelPosition="left" columns="${revenueAndLicensesColumns}" data="${revenueAndLicensesData}" />
   <gvisualization:imageCandlestickChart elementId="imagecandlestickchart" columns="${gainersLoserColumns}" data="${gainersLoserData}" />
   <gvisualization:gauge elementId="gauge" width="${400}" height="${120}" redFrom="${90}" redTo="${100}" yellowFrom="${75}" yellowTo="${90}" minorTicks="${5}" columns="${systemPerformanceColumns}" data="${systemPerformanceData}" />
   <gvisualization:table elementId="table" width="${400}" height="${130}" columns="${employeeColumns}" data="${employeeData}" select="selectHandler" ready="readyHandler"/>
   <gvisualization:map elementId="map" columns="${mapColumns}" data="${mapData}" />
   <gvisualization:annotatedTimeLine elementId="annotatedtimeline" columns="${pensColumns}" data="${pensData}" />
   <gvisualization:orgChart elementId="orgchart" allowHtml="${true}" columns="${orgColumns}" data="${orgData}" />
   <gvisualization:intensityMap elementId="intensitymap" columns="${populationColumns}" data="${populationData}" />
   <gvisualization:geoMap elementId="geomap" columns="${popularityColumns}" data="${popularityData}" />
   <gvisualization:geoChart elementId="geochart" width="${556}" height="${347}" columns="${popularityColumns}" data="${popularityData}" />
   <gvisualization:motionChart elementId="motionchart" columns="${fruitColumns}" data="${fruitData}" />
   <gvisualization:treeMap elementId="treemap" minColor="#f00" midColor="#ddd" maxColor="#0d0" headerHeight="${15}" fontColor="black" showScale="${true}" columns="${marketByRegionColumns}" data="${marketByRegionData}" />
   <gvisualization:timeLine elementId="timeline" columns="${timelineColumns}" data="${timelineData}" />
   <gvisualization:calendarChart elementId="calendarchart" columns="${calendarColumns}" data="${calendarData}" />
   <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart">Pie Chart</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="piechart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imagepiechart">Pie Chart (Image)</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="imagepiechart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart">Bar Chart</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="barchart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imagebarchart">Bar Chart (Image)</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="imagebarchart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <a href="http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart.html">Bubble Chart</a>
          </td>
          <td>
              <div id="bubblechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart">Column Chart</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="columnchart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart">Area Chart</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="areachart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imageareachart">Area Chart (Image)</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="imageareachart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart">Line Chart</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="linechart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imagelinechart">Line Chart (Image)</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="imagelinechart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart">Scatter Chart</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="scatterchart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart">Stepped Area Chart</a>
       </td>
       <td>
           <div id="steppedareachart"></div>
       </td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imagesparkline">Sparkline (Image)</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="imagesparkline"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart">Candlestick Chart</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="candlestickchart" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imagecandlestickchart">Candlestick Chart (Image)</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="imagecandlestickchart" style='width: 300px; height: 300px;'></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart">Combo Chart</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="combochart" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge">Gauge</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="gauge"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table">Table</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="table"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map">Map</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline">Annotated Time Line</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="annotatedtimeline" style='width: 700px; height: 240px;'></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart">Organizational Chart</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="orgchart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intensitymap">Intensity Map</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="intensitymap"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap">Geo Map</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="geomap"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart">Geo Chart</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="geochart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart">Motion Chart</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="motionchart"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap">Tree Map</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="treemap" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline">Timeline</a>
           </td>
           <td>
               <div id="timeline"></div>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar">Calendar</a>
           </td>
           <td>
               <div id="calendarchart"></div>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I used to have this working in Grails 2.* and started a new project and have the same problem you are.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this problem I looked up the internet and here is the solution.
Modify the _visualization_javascripts.gsp file in goggle visualisation api as follows:

```
changed from <%=row %> TO <%=raw(row) %>
changed from <%=visualizationData.options%> TO <%=raw(visualizationData.options)%>
```

Comment: It worked (second time around, first just crashed the JVM due to typos I guess)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to you Config.groovy.

Found this on the commit history from the developer itself.

```
googleVisualization.grails.views.gsp.codecs.scriptlet = "none"
```

~Dixie