# Grails what is the correct way of reloading a gsp

Tags: grails

**LAST UPDATE: It seems like the problem was related to geomap and not wanting to update, have now rewritten it using jvectormap as that fits my requirement better.**

So

Got an application which have two boxes, one contains a bunch of controllers (resolution, region and stuff). It makes a remote call to a second box which then takes that data and extracts a bunch of things, sets up the data then sends to google visualisation.

However, if I use render in the class it works perfectly, can see that it picks up the right variables, and that they look like they do from the start.

Problem is, if I let it run without render, then the gsp page does not reload, and it is displaying the same code as was originally loaded (and actually, the picture that is generated disappears)

Is there a way I should tell the gsp page to reload or similar?

Below is the remotesubmit that works like a charm (if the controller renders output)

```
    <g:formRemote name="mapRepmote" on404="alert('not found!')" update="page-body"
              url="[controller: 'mapren', action:'show']">
    <g:if test="${listreg == 'true'}">
        Regulation: <g:select name="regsel" from="${reglist}" value="${regreq}" />
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
        Regulation: ${regreq}
    </g:else>

    Resolution: &nbsp;<g:select name="ressel" from="${reslist}" value="${resreq}" />

     Region: <g:select name="mapsel" from="${maplist}" value="${mapreq}" />

<div id="bupdate"><Button type="submit">Update</Button></div>
</g:formRemote>
```

**Edit: What on earth**
So been playing around and get the same results over and over again.
So the show action from the mapren controller does seem to be called. I can see the calls to the db layer and all. And if I add three render statements I can see that the requests are coming in.

```
    def show(String regsel, String mapsel, String ressel) {
        String mapcode
        switch (mapsel) {
            case "World": 
                mapcode="world"
                break
            case "Europe": 
                mapcode=150
                break
            case "Asia": 
                mapcode=140
                break
            case "Africa": 
                mapcode=002
                break
            case "Central Ameirca": 
                mapcode=017
                break
            case "Pacific": 
                mapcode=035
                break
            default:
                mapcode="world"
        }

        def restem = ressel.split('x')
        String mwidth = restem[0]
        String mheight = restem[1]
        render "I was asked to show reg: ${params.regsel} <BR>map: ${params.mapsel}<BR>Resolution ${params.ressel}<BR>"
        render "will generate map for ${regsel} on code ${mapcode} resolutio"
        render "I will ${mwidth} and ${mheight}"
        def query = Regstat.where {
            (reg==regsel)
        }
        def regcolumns = [['string', 'Country'],['number', regsel + 'Status']]
        def results = query.list(sort:"lupdate")
        def regdata = []
        results.each {
            regdata << [it.country.countryname,it.status]
        }
        def RegColors = ['0xF0F0F0','0x66CCFF','0x0000FF','0xCC66FF','0x9900CC','0x7D7D7D']
        [reg_columns: regcolumns, reg_data: regdata,reg_colors: RegColors, regioncode: mapcode, wwidth: mwidth, wheight: mheight]
    }
}
```

But if I remove the render calls, I would have expected that the show.gsp would get loaded?
But no such luck. 
Have attached the show.gsp file. Note, it does is generated when index does a  against it to generate the first geomap.

```
<%@ page import="org.grails.plugins.google.visualization.util.DateUtil" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABCDEFG" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    </head>
       <body>

       <script type="text/javascript">
          function selectHandler(e) {
              alert('A table row was selected');
          }
       </script>
       <gvisualization:geoMap elementId="page-body" showLegend="${false}" region="${regioncode}" width="${wwidth}" height="${wheight}" colors="${reg_colors}" columns="${reg_columns}" data="${reg_data}" />


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That should work without any action on your part. What version of Grails?

Comment: 2.4 something, less than a month old. Could it be because the gsp in that div is initially loaded using <g:include>

Comment: OK, groovy 3.6.1, not certain what I got 2.4 from. Seems like the code kind of works, can see the correct calls to the database to collect the information, but for some reason the html code does not update, I can see the old code (I load an initial view into the div, same controller and action), and its that data that is there if I do a view source on the browser.

Comment: That sounds odd. If you can isolate a small test case in a new app that's similar to your code but doesn't have anything proprietary, create a JIRA issue and we can take a look. Run `grails bug-report` to zip up your test project, and attach that - `bug-report` includes code but omits the target directory and other derived items. The latest version of Grails is 2.4.3 so you were right the first time. It's not likely to be affected by the version of Groovy, but that's easy to figure out given the Grails version. And no, I doubt an include would affect it, but this is a weird one, so maybe :)

Comment: One step forward, fifty steps back. Created a view called show, then created a template called mapdisplay, and it kind of works. I render the mapdisplay view manually, and it updates the data, but for some reason it never seem to regenerate the map using geomap, and I can't quite understand if it is suppose to or not, will set up one with static data.

Answer (score 0):

OK, partial answer, but one step forward a couple back:)

So moved it around and ended up creating a straight forward static version of mapren which have a controller (staticmapren) and a template (_mapdisp). These do seem to work correctly, every time a request comes in, the page now updates correctly with text.

Problem is that the geomap is only displayed first time around. 
Was fighting with this quite a lot, then realised that maybe (just maybe) the javascript console might have something to say about this...
Yes it does as it turns out...

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

**Red herring:** Well, maybe, seems like that one comes up with or without reloading. It happens after about 40 seconds, so still dont have a clue why the map only turns up the first time

My problem is, what on earth can I do about this, could I potentially destroy the object and get a new one each time.

The simplified version of the controller is:

class StaticmaprenController {

```
def index() {
    render "I am an index"
}
def show(String regsel, String mapsel, String ressel) {
    String mapcode
    mapcode="world"


    def restem = ressel.split('x')
    String mwidth = restem[0]
    String mheight = restem[1]
    //render "I was asked to show reg: ${params.regsel} <BR>map: ${params.mapsel}<BR>Resolution ${params.ressel}<BR>"
    //render "will generate map for ${regsel} on code ${mapcode} resolutio"
    //render "I will ${mwidth} and ${mheight}"
    def regcolumns = [['string', 'Country'],['number', regsel + ' Status']]
    def RegColors = ['0xF0F0F0','0x66CCFF','0x0000FF','0xCC66FF','0x9900CC','0x7D7D7D']

    def regdata = [['UK','3'],['United States','2'],['Russia','4']]
    String content = g.render (template:"mapdisp", model:[reg_columns: regcolumns, reg_data: regdata,reg_colors: RegColors, regioncode: mapcode, wwidth: mwidth, wheight: mheight])
    render content
    [reg_columns: regcolumns, reg_data: regdata,reg_colors: RegColors, regioncode: mapcode, wwidth: mwidth, wheight: mheight]

}
```

}

And the _mapdisp template

```
      Going to elementId="page-body" <BR>
      Testing some stuff showLegend="${false}" <BR>
      Will do region="${regioncode}" <BR>
       Lets go width="${wwidth}" and height="${wheight}"<BR>
       And these are the Beutiful colours colors="${reg_colors}" <BR>
       Now columns columns="${reg_columns}"<BR>
       And the data="${reg_data}"<BR>


       <script type="text/javascript">
          function selectHandler(e) {
              alert('A table row was selected');
          }
       </script>
              <gvisualization:geoMap elementId="geomap2" showLegend="${false}" region="${regioncode}" width="${wwidth}" height="${wheight}" colors="${reg_colors}" columns="${reg_columns}" data="${reg_data}" />
    </body>
    <div id="geomap2"></div>
</html>
```

And to get geomap and google visualisation you will need to install the api, and do some fix with raw ([Google Visualization API. Graphs are not displaying in gsp pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776975/google-visualization-api-graphs-are-not-displaying-in-gsp-pages))

I have also loaded the api in the main body of the page.
(Adding the following lines)

```
<%@ page import="org.grails.plugins.google.visualization.util.DateUtil" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="genmap-desk"/>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABCDEFG" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Any suggestions what I can do about Maximum call stack?